# What is it called when you use quotation marks to signify repeating a word or phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing

For example, let's say I'm copying instructions by hand. The original instructions say:

> - Multiply the first by the second
> - Integrate the third with the fourth
> - Integrate the third with the fifth

And on a page I write:

> - Multiply the first by the second
> - Integrate the third with the fourth
> - "" with the fifth

I know this example is silly, but hopefully it's clear what I mean.

What is this called?

Comment: *Requote with quotes*

Comment: Note you only need one (double) quotation mark in your last bullet point.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They are ***ditto marks***.

*ditto* stems from the Tuscan dialect of the Italian *detto* - 'said'; Latin *dictus* - 'said'.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ditto_mark).